# R: unable to set try catch in loop

Tags: r, exception

I have an R code where , in case the test function function fails (raises an error) at some i and j, I need to remove that column j from the B. And corresponding jth row and column from A. Store index j in some array for further reference and continue running the loop.

I tried work around using try catch but it is not working.. Nothing is updated in A matrix.

```
for i in 1:no_of_B_col{
 for j in 1:no_of_B_col{
  if(i!=j){
   tryCatch({out<-test(B[i],B[j]);A[i,j]=test(B[i],B[j])},
            error=function(e){
                   B=B[,-j]
                   A=A[-j,]
                   A=A[,-j]
                   mylist=c(mylist,j)
  }
 }
}
```

After this the loop runs completely. But nothing is updated in matrix A nor is the size of B reduced.

Comment: Each time in the loop, `out` will be over-written, so your `test(...)` calc on it is wasted on all but the last iteration. Regardless, the code in your `error=` function is assigning the updated values within the context of the `function(e)`, not the parent environment. While I usually dislike the use of `<<-`, if you instead do `B <<- B[,-k]` (etc), I think you'll see the updates you need. (The `out` calc may not be a waste if all you need it for is to look for an `error`, in which case keep it :-)

Comment: You are changing the variables `A` and `B` inside the error function only. Those changes are lost as soon as the function exits.

Comment: But frankly, it seems like there might be a better way to do these tests and remove errant columns instead of a double-`for`-loop with `tryCatch`.